# website apache-tomcat in ubuntu aws is not working

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I lost the aws private key, now I create a new key and access my previous ec2 instance. Now it seems my tomcat is not working

When I issued the ps command, I got

```
ps aux | grep java
```

Output

> ubuntu    1381  1.2 10.1 2395040 410176 pts/0  Sl   05:36   0:18
>   /usr/bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/logging.properties
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/endorsed -classpath /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   -Dcatalina.base=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57 -Dcatalina.home=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

To see which ports are listening

```
netstat -tlnp
```

[image]

*But I don't see any port 80*

Security group as previously.
[image]

/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/server.xml
[image]

My question is do I need to open port 80 to make it working, if so how?

Comment: what is showing in your catalina.out file

Answer (score 0):

@Scary Wombat, thank you for your information. I have looked at catalina.out file. It mentioned that it is not able to write to log file. I have looked at the log file of owner and group. It was written by ubuntu, by previous log file was written by root. I tried to start tomcat as root and it works.